# Reverse email proxy hiding original senders

Tags: email, reverse-proxy

I need some kind of reverse proxy for Email protocol which hides original senders of emails.

Let's say we have a domain `@bar.com`. When `a@foo.com` sends an email to `b@bar.com` I need to proxy it to `c@baz.com` AND hide the original sender (in my case `a@foo.com`), so `b@bar.com` is going to be the only sender.

When `c@baz.com` replies – it should go the whole way around, and `c@baz.com` should NOT be shown as the sender, `b@bar.com` should be the only one.

In the case of the following chain `a@foo.com -> b@bar.com -> c@baz.com` c@baz.com should NOT know about a@foo.com.

When c@baz.com replies, and email goes `c@baz.com -> b@bar.com -> a@foo.com` a@foo.com should NOT know about c@baz.com.

Is it possible to implement by setting up MX/Email servers properly or custom logic/code should be in the middle?